# When releasing update to production how to proceed with backend update?

Tags: android, google-play, updates, backend, google-play-console

Knowing that releasing an update to Google Play could take several hours to a day, what would be the proper way to synchronize the backend?

-- By synchronizing the backend I mean updating stored procedures, adding/deleting columns from tables, and among other things. --

Synchronizing the backend after APK submission but before update goes live could disrupt usage for current users because their app haven't updated yet to react the new backend changes.

Likewise, synchronizing the backend too late would also disrupt usage as both the new app and old app cannot use the backend properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice in this area is to not rely on simultaneous release. Remember, even if Google Play updates instantly, users won't always. What many big companies do is:

Suppose you were moving from version 10 to version 11 of your backend and client:

1. make sure the client has built into every network call a possible response which is a code "needs new version". If the client gets this code as a response, then instead of proceeding it should show the user an option "You need to update to the latest version" and link to Google Play. This could also be done with a service like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/).
2. In the backend, make sure you support both the new client (in this case v11) and the old client (in this case v10). This requires some software engineering but normally isn't too difficult.
3. In your backend have a live configuration variable which configures which client version you require. Start with this set to 10 (the old client).
4. Release v11 of your backend. At this point all the customers are on V10 client talking to V11 backend.
5. Once your backend rollout is complete, release your new client to the Play Store. At this point some users will have updated and be on V10 clients, and some will be on V11.
6. After giving the users a little while to update (maybe a week) update your remote config to insist all users are using V11 clients.

Then you can work on your new backend, which needs to support only clients V11 and V12.

An alternative, which is less safe but needs less software engineering is to use Google Play's timed publishing. [Instructions are on this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282). In this process you send your app to Google to be reviewed well beforehand, and ask them to publish at a particular time after the review is complete. This means Google will make your app live at a precise time. You could then update your servers at that time.

You could still have a small window (minutes) where the Play servers in different parts of the world are not in sync. Also, the Play client does some client side caching of the app description, so even though the Play store has updated, the user might not see the new version for a little while (possibly hours). This is why I recommend the procedure in the first part of my answer.